# Dynamic CLI - Search StackOverflow without leaving your terminal

Tags: app

**About**
A modern, user-friendly command-line for API testing and if you are stuck - Search and browse StackOverflow without leaving the CLI.

**Usage**
Dynamic CLI allows users to search for keywords/issues with some relevant tags.
Usage: Dynamic [OPTIONS]

*Options*:

```
-st, --start -> Introduces Dynamic CLI
-v, --version -> Gives the Version of the CLI
-s, --search -> Search a question on Stackoverflow
-d, --debug -> Turn on Debugging mode
-h, --help -> Shows this message and exit
```

**Contributing**

Feel free to contribute here:
[Github Repo link](https://github.com/IndianOpenSourceFoundation/dynamic-cli)